# AS3 OOP: Button not showing

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, actionscript

I am learning AS3 OOP and trying to do some simple stuff, here I am just trying to add a button onto the stage and handle the click event.

Here is my simple code:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class External extends MovieClip
    {

    private var counter:Number;
    public var HitButtonA:RedButton;

        public function External() // constructor
        {
         HitButtonA= new RedButton();
         HitButtonA.x = 40; 
         HitButtonA.y = 65; 
         addChild(HitButtonA);

         setupListeners();    
         counter=0;         
        }


    public function setupListeners()
    { trace("bbbb");
        HitButtonA.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, hitButtA);
    }

    public function hitButtA(e:MouseEvent)
    {
        //display.text=String(++counter);
        trace("aaaaa");
    }



    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it does not even add the button onto the stage, no error or anything... any idea whats wrong?

Comment: Did you point the ActionScript linkage in the FLA for RedButton to any MovieClip in the library?

Comment: I linked it like this: http://picthost.net/v.php?id=adc8325521d37df4d6924a0452026fe7

Comment: Is your RedButton class extending the SimpleButton class?

Comment: I dont think so... I pasted all the code I am using.

Comment: Try placing a trace in your External constructor to see if it is being called properly. If so, make sure that your External Object is being added to the stage.

Comment: Constructor trace is getting executed. "make sure that your External Object is being added to the stage" not sure how to do that. Sorry, Im a total noob at this.

Comment: When you instantiate your External object, var myExternalVarName:External = new External(); do you ever add it to the stage such as stage.addChild(myExternalVarName); ?

Comment: HAHAHA! That was it! Thank you so much! Please add your suggestion as an answer so I can pick that as the winner. Quick question, is it possible to do that in the instantiation itself?

Comment: The code I used: var exampleExternal:External = new External();
stage.addChild(exampleExternal);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as though you forgot to add your External object to the stage.

Make sure you add it like so:

```
var myExternal:External = new External();
stage.addChild(myExternal);
```

**Edit:**

> Thanks! Anyway to do both those two lines as one line? So that as I
>   instantiate the above it gets added to the stage?

Yes, if you do not require the reference, simply call `stage.addChild(new External());` 
Alternatively, it is possible to add the child to the stage through the constructor by passing a reference of the stage through the constructor `var myExternal:External = new External(this.stage);`.

Then you need to modify your constructor like so:

```
public function External(DisplayObject theStage) // constructor
    {
     HitButtonA= new RedButton();
     HitButtonA.x = 40; 
     HitButtonA.y = 65; 
     addChild(HitButtonA);

     setupListeners();    
     counter=0;
     theStage.addChild(theStage);
    }
```

However, this isn't a very good practice as it promotes an inside out perspective which may cause troubles later.

Comment: Thanks! Anyway to do both those two lines as one line? So that as I instantiate the above it gets added to the stage?

Comment: Thanks again! Have a fab day!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a few possible mistakes you could make:

- External.as is not your document class and you haven't created and/or added the External class object to the stage.
- If External.as is your document class by your design, check if it's really set as a document class. If you're using Flash Professional in the properties panel click in the edit button right of your document class input box, if a blank generated class is created - you've got the source of your mistake.
- Check if you can add an instance of RedButton just by frame scripting

  var rButton:RedButton = new RedButton();
  addChild(rButton);

Other then that I see no problem with your code.

Hope that help, good luck!